# Submit HTML form with Javascript link as well as confirm box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, confirmation

I am trying to submit form data, but instead of using the standard "Submit" button I want to use a regular HTML link.  However, when I click this link I want to have a confirmation box asking the user to continue or cancel.  I have both parts of the puzzle, but when I put them together they don't play nice.  This is what I currently have for Javascript code:

```
function confirmSubmit()
{
var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this file?");
if (agree)
    return true ;
else
    return false ;
}
function submitform() {
    document.forms["delete14"].submit();
}
```

And for the HTML I have:

```
<a href="javascript:submitform()" onClick="javascript:confirmSubmit()">link text</a>
```

The confirmation box does pop up as intended and the form does submit properly.  But currently the form submits even if the user clicks "no" on the confirmation box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
function confirmSubmit()
{
var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this file?");
if (agree)
    document.forms["delete14"].submit();
else
    return false ;
}
```

Comment: Wow I feel a little silly now.  Most of my work with coding so far has been PHP so what little Javascript I have right now has been snippets I've copied and pasted.  Either way, thanks a great deal!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use a link if you don't want one, use a styled span (or a button, which says to the user "click me and something will happen" rather than a link, which says "click me and I'll take you to another page").

Also, don't use "javascript:" in an attribute that expects a value that is script, it will be seen as a useless label.

Anyhow, your issue is that you have two listeners on the link:

```
<a href="javascript:submitform()" onClick="javascript:confirmSubmit()">link text</a>
```

The one in the href will submit the form unconditionally. So use a span and get rid of the href:

```
<span style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline"
   onclick="confirmSubmit()">link text</span>
```